# Is there any class or method for core's operations in SolrNet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, solr, solrnet

I'm working on eCommerce site which is based on ASP.NET MVC3. I've implement SolrNet 3.6 which is configured as two cores named 'core-indexing' and 'core-live'. 'core-indexing' for indexing data due to avoid down time.

Now I want to reload 'core-live' after indexing is complete for reflecting changes on live core.

So How can I do this?
Is there any class or method for core's operations in SolrNet?

Comment: try posting on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a set of [Core Commands](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/master/SolrNet/Commands/Cores) in SolrNet. You can see some examples of how to use them by looking at the unit tests in [CoreAdminTests.cs](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet.Tests/SolrCoreAdminTests.cs) Please note that these commands were recently added (within the last 6 months) and may only be available by pulling latest code from GitHub and compiling. I cannot remember if the Core Commands  are available in the [SolrNet-0.4.0.2002](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/downloads/list) Beta2 release.